# question with rl circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, thevenin

I have an assignment in my electronics 1 class:
http://prntscr.com/jcdz1m

My idea was to find a Thevenin equivalent, convert it to Norton then i would get Io and calculate the graph for I1 and I2 for(0->100μs).

What can I do to calculate I1 and I2 for(-10μs->0μs)? I cannot perform circuit analysis since I cannot convert my inductor to a resistor.

Comment: First of all, do you know that the inductor acts the opposite to a capacitor in an RL circuit? When DC voltage is applied, the current starts at minimum and charges to max, and the voltage starts at maximum and discharges to zero, as it is essentially a short circuit. Have you found the time constant of the circuit? That should give you a hint as to how you can proceed with doing your graph

Comment: @MCG thanks for your response.Yea i do know it and i can calculate r/l in the small circuit when i have to make the graph.My problem is that the task asks to make a graph for -10 to +100 ms, meaning that i need to calculate the current in the inductor which is equal with the current in the 15 kohm resistor.How can i calculate I1 and I2 for the -10-0 ms time, since the inductor will not be charging the circuit this time and it will act using the voltage source.

Comment: If i use Thevenins then use change it with nortons equivalent , i will get a current In, is this the Io i am looking for?thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When the switch is opened, inductor acts like a current source with \$I_o\$. Where \$I_o \$ is the current which was flowing through resistor 15 kohms, at steady state ( when switch is closed for long time, inductor can be considered a short).
- Then you can use RL circuit current equation to solve for current at any time t.
  $$I_1(t)=I_2(t)=I(t) = I_oe^{-tR/L}$$ where R = 15k + 5k ohms

Comment: Nicely explained. +1 for this answer!